# Как написвть вложенный клас в sass

Tags: css, sass

Здраствуйте! Как мне написать этот код на sass?

```
.opencategory:hover > .headercategory {
     display: block;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.opencategory
  &:hover
    >.headercategory
      display: block
```